# Why can the c# compiler not resolve the argument types of a lambda expression in a ternary operator?

Tags: c#, lambda, type-inference, ternary-operator

I have this code:

```
Action<A, B> fnUpdate = (someBool) ? (a, b) => a.propOne = b : (a, b) => a.propTwo = d;
```

Why can the compiler not resolve the types of `a` and `b`, just because it is assigned in a ternary operator? it seems quite straight forward at face value.

Comment: try to add brackets over the functions - its somewhat ambiguous.

Comment: nope that didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# compiler tries to create the lambdas independently and cannot unambiguously determine the type. Hence cast it to work as expected....

```
Action<A, B> fnUpdate = (someBool) 
                       ? (Action<A, B> (a, b) => a.propOne = b 
                       : (Action<A, B> (a, b) => a.propTwo = d);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast at least one of the two functions:

```
Action<A, B> fnUpdate = someBool
   ? (Action<A, B>)((a, b) => a.propOne = b)
   : (a, b) => a.propTwo = b;
```